# Custom function for mosaic seams in Python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-merge

I was wondering if there is a way to implement a custom function for creating seams between the rasters that create a mosaic. More specifically, if I create a mosaic with gdal_merge or gdalwarp, the images will be laid on top of each other one after the other without specifying where the seam between the images should be. I was wondering how (with which specific module in gdal) would it be possible to implement a function in Python that creates a seam like the one made with Area Voronoi Diagrams with  Overlap described here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.725.3922&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

I'm very new to GIS, however I struggle to find anything of help on the internet and I wonder if it needs to be implemented completely from scratch... Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: gdalwarp has the concept of "cutlines" which sounds like what you're after:  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-cutline

Comment: Could you give a small example of what you are looking for? The paper _Pan et al (2009)_ describe a method to create Voronoi polygons based on the extent of multiple orthoimages. Probably you need (1) OGR ( or fiona/Geopandas) to find the nodes, (2) then some library like (Geopandas or geovoronoi to build the seams and (3) finally use gdalwarp (with cutline option) to generate _Pan et al (2009)_ like outputs.